# Check if order note contains specific words and display message in WooCommerce customer completed order email notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm trying to add a specific function to my customer-completed-order template file in WooCommerce.

I want that function to check if an order note is containing specific word "Loren ipsum" and if yes, show a my selected message.

This is how my customer-completed-order.php email template file looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer completed order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>

<p>
<?php
    
        $comment_obj   = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $customer_note = $comment_obj->comment_content;
        $word = "Loren ipsum";
        $mystring = $customer_note;
        $order_id = $order->get_id();

        // ACF field, will give an error if you don't use this specific plugin
        //$pristatysimePatys = get_field('pristatysime_patys', $order_id);

        if (strpos($mystring, $word) !== false) {
            $message = "Your order number " . $order_id . " is sended. " . $customer_note ." .";
        } elseif ($pristatysimePatys) {
            $message = "Your order number " . $order_id . " is sended. The custom field checkbox in order are selected.";
        } else {
            $message = "There are no Loren Ipsum in order notes and custom field with checkbox is not selected.";
        }
        printf($message);
    
    ?>
</p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

But I do a mistake somewhere, because even if the words "Loren ipsum" is in order note, it will show my else result in the email. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes regarding your code attempt:

- No need to overwrite template files, you can use the `woocommerce_email_order_details` hook and then target the correct email notification via `$email->id`
- [get_comment()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment/) retrieves comment data given a comment ID or comment object. To get order notes you can use `wc_get_order_notes()` or `$order->get_customer_note()` to get the customer note during checkout.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Target specific email notification
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        // Get order id
        $order_id = $order->get_id();

        // Get order notes
        $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
            'order_id'  => $order_id,
            'order_by'  => 'date_created',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
        ));
        
        // Notes is NOT empty
        if ( ! empty( $order_notes ) ) {
            foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
                // DEBUG information, delete afterwards
                echo '<p style="color:red;font-size:20px;">' . $order_note->content . '</p>';

                // PHP 8
                if ( str_contains( $order_note->content, 'Loren ipsum' ) ) {
                    echo '<p style="color:blue;font-size:20px;">My text 1</p>';
                }

                // Before PHP 8
                if ( strpos( $order_note->content, 'Loren ipsum' ) !== false ) {
                    echo '<p style="color:blue;font-size:20px;">My text 2</p>';
                }
            }
        }

        // OR get customer note
        $customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
        
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $customer_note ) ) {
            echo '<p style="color:green;font-size:20px;">' . $customer_note . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action ('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_woocommerce_email_order_details', 1, 4 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme)